# enable button with state of toggle

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, toggle, yup

I am working on typescript with React and I am bit new. I have a button that has to be enable if the switch is off and on different valid states for when the switch is on. The valid states for when the switch is on are working well but the issue I am facing is  when the switch is off after being turned on the button is not enabled.Here is the validation I am using

Comment: I can help you out but please provide more details or share the code related to how you are handling the switch state and button enabling/disabling in your React component since that is where the issue is occurring? Specifically, where are you checking the switch state and setting the button's disabled state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a switch is turned off, it can affect/change isDirty. One potential solution is to also check if the switch is off

```
{currentStep?.nextStep('creation') != null && (
  <Button
    appearance="primary"
    className="mc-ml-auto"
    type={"submit"}
    disabled={!isSwitch && (!isValid || !isDirty)}
    onClick={handleSubmit}
  >
    {currentStep?.id === steps.summary.id ? 'Confirmer' : 'Continuer'}
  </Button>
)}
```

side note: if you are using your button within a form and it is type submit, you do not need to use on click and can instead use `<form onSubmit>` which helps trigger validation if applied.

if your button is outside a form then you can give your form an id and pass the id to the button `form` prop